# Bundle multiple API calls in a single transaction

Tags: api, soap, transaction

Is there any way that I can bundle multiple SOAP API calls into a single transaction, such that if one or more fails the entire transaction is rolled back?

In my particular case, I am attempting to post a shipment and add tracking information. However if the posting of the shipment or adding tracking information fails, I would like to log the error and retry once it is resolved. This would be better than having a shipment without tracking information.

If this is not possible in the current SOAP API, I will delete the shipment upon failure. I would prefer to use a transaction though.

Comment: It's not possible out of the box. You could check the return value of your last SOAP call and continue your update depending on the return.

Comment: That is the kind of logic that I plan to implement, just hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The closest Magento comes is the `call` method — in the XML-RPC and V1 SOAP APIs.  This method allows you to send multiple method calls in a single HTTP request. While I've never looked deeply into it, it's always been my assumption `call` isn't available in the V2 API since coming up with a typed WSDL for it would be impossible.

Unfortunately, `call` has no rollback mechanism.  If you want this functionality, you'd need to write a custom extension that implements a [custom API method](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html), and then install extension into your system.